# How to add audio/spotify attachments to azure bot service?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I currently have a node bot embedded on my web app via direct line but I am struggling to attach:
Spotify Audio

I am trying to do so by using the URL attachment or an adaptive card, but the spotify embed doesn't play

Below is the code I use:

```
    var send = {
        text: "stuff",
        attachments: [
            contentType: "audio/ogg",
            contentUrl: "spotifyEmbedUrl"
        ]
    }

    await stepContext.context.sendActivity(send);
```

I am unsure on how I can get spotify audio to play.

Is there a way I can return HTML code (and so get around it by adding an iframe into the chat etc?)

OR maybe I could create a modal popup that I could create the embed iframe?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-webchat) as your client or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't just send a file to a web page and it automatically start playing. Additionally, while Spotify provides embed URLs, which are *not* a direct link to an audio file, you can't simply tell the browser to play the file.

However, Spotify provides the embed code for displaying a play button that can be used in a page to play a song. Assuming you are using Web Chat in a web site (and even if you're not, this will give you an idea) and that, from the code you supplied, you are wanting to send the song in an activity, you can achieve this by sending the embed code in the activity, instead, via Web Chat's store. When the activity is received, the embed code is passed to a function to update the page and, thus, display the play button.

[image]

*Be aware, the play button is essentially a UI widget, not a media player. There is no functionality available for telling the play button to auto play, stop, or anything else. The most you can do is display the button after which the user will be required to interact with it.*

*Also, this is a someone bare bones, simplified implementation. There are many things that aren't accounted for - please don't consider this a complete solution. There are aspects you will need to consider (e.g. multiple cards that utilize a `postBack` action).*

---

**In your bot:** You want to send the embed code in an activity. Whether that is an `event`, `message`, or something else, is up to you. As you can see below, I have chosen to send a hero card that initiates a `postBack` when the button is pressed (a `postBack` sends data behind the scenes without displaying the action to the user).

```js
const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
    "Rome Wasn't Built in a Day",
    null,
    CardFactory.actions([
        {
            type: 'postBack',
            title: 'Read more',
            value: `<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/6lzd7dxYNuVSvh7sJDHIa3" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>`
        }
    ]),
    {
        subtitle: 'Artist: Morcheeba',
        text: 'Album: Parts of the Process - released 2003'
    }
);

await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card]});
```

**Web Chat:** First, use Web Chat's store to filter on incoming activities that include attachments where the button type (action) is `postBack`. When the condition is met, get the last card rendered and assign an event listener. When the card's button is clicked, get the 'spotify' container element and update the `innerHTML` with the embed code that was sent in the activity, thus displaying the play button.*

*Please note, the `setTimeout()` used below is necessary for enabling the click action. Without the time out, the event listener being appended to the button would occur before the `store` finished processing the incoming activity.*

```js
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
<div class='spotify'></div>

[...]

const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {
    const activity = action.payload?.activity;
    if (activity.attachments && activity.attachments[0].content.buttons[0]?.type === 'postBack') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const spotifyIframe = activity.attachments[0].content.buttons[0].value
        let cards = document.querySelectorAll( '.ac-adaptiveCard' )
        let cardLength = cards.length;
        let card = cards[ cardLength - 1 ];
        card.querySelectorAll( 'button' ).forEach( button => {
          button.addEventListener( 'click', ( e ) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const spotifyContainer = document.querySelector( '.spotify' );
            spotifyContainer.innerHTML = spotifyIframe
          } )
        } );
      }, 300);
    }
    next( action );
} );
```

[image]

Hope of help!